# Crontab on Rpi not running Python script

Tags: python, cron

I have a simple problem that I cannot seem to find an answer to even though I have done some research. I am trying to run a python script via crontab (I have never worked with crontab before this haha). Currently, this is what I have in my `crontab -e`

```
*/2 * * * * /home/pi/path_to_script/fileName.py
```

I want the script to be run every 2 minutes. The script '*fileName.py*' writes to a text file so I know whether the crontab has run the script or not: the text file is never changed. I also have some `print()` lines in the script and those messages are never outputted. Furthermore, the first line in fileName.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

So I believe I got the shebang directory down. I also tried the following in the `crontab -e`

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/path_to_script/fileName.py
```

and that does not seem to work. Also I have complied fileName.py with chmod +x so the script runs when I type ./fileName.py in the command line.

Any ideas as to why the crontab does not execute?

Thanks

Comment: try this: 2 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/path_to_script/fileName.py

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work

Comment: I am assuming that you are replacing the path_to_script and filename.py with those for your script. Also who owns the file and what are the permissions on it?

Comment: I just used path_to_script and fileName.py to show what I was doing. They are the acutal file path name and file name in my crontab line.  And I am the only one using the RPi so I am assuming I own file with all permissions to it?

Comment: Is there the needed blank line after the crontab entry?

Comment: *print() lines in the script and those messages are never outputted* that is not going to work. There's typically nowhere to output to when running from cron.

Comment: send the output to a file: `script.py >> /home/pi/cron.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

cron jobs run with different environment variables than your usual terminal session, most notably a more limited `PATH`. Copy the following to a file (`test.sh`), run it with `env -i sh test.sh`, and see what happens,

```
#!/bin/sh
HOME=/home/pi
LOGNAME=pi
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/pi
/home/pi/path_to_script/fileName.py
```

Comment: Would I make this .sh executable and make the crontab call this .sh file?

Comment: Assuming its called `test.sh`, run it with `env -i sh test.sh`, you don't even have to chmod `test.sh`, and the `env` will clear the environment first.

Comment: Run the `env ...` right from the shell, not crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is the Raspberry Pi forum, there's a big chance you're accessing GPIOs in your Python script - correct me if I'm wrong and I'll shamefully hit the delete button :P

Anyway, if I'm right try adding your script to root's crontab via `sudo crontab -e` and keep the absolute path like you're doing here: `*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/path_to_script/fileName.py`

As @joan mentioned in the comments, you need to have an empty line / newline after a cron entry so make sure you hit Enter once after entering/pasting the line into the crontab.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not accessing any GPIO pins. Is sudo crontab -e necessary when only accessing GPIO pins? The RPi is accessing another device via Modbus in the fileName.py. I simply want the crontab to start fileName.py

Comment: @RPiNoob_16 Ok. `sudo`/root privileges are required for various things; not just GPIO access - it often causes trouble because Linux is quite restrictive out of the box, the Pi user is unprivileged per default and everybody wants to play around with GPIO. Anything requiring `sudo` should be able to run without it if it's placed in root's crontab which you access via `sudo crontab -e`. The `@reboot` directive often only works in root's crontab as well. Anyway, if you've tried these things to no avail, I'll re-consider and eventually edit or delete my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the crontab file. In buster rpi: the cron tab MUST have:
**(tab)***(tab)user(tab)Executable
for the Executable to run every minute.

It took me hours to figure this out.  I was missing the tab after hour's *.  I tried every other trick, but the (tab) solved it.

Bill

Comment: Sorry, Bill, but this is just incorrect: https://www.google.com/search?q=crontab+tabs+or+spaces Possibly you corrected some actual error (there does have to be at least a space) at the same time.